# Change sub category to root category in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Hi friends i'm newbie to Magento. I'm using Magento ver. 1.7.0.2. I suddenly dragged the one of the root categories(RC1) into other root category(RC2) now RC1 has become the sub category of RC2 as i try to drag from out of RC2 it not becoming a root category rather it becoming the sub category of other root categories but RC1 not able to become Root Category. I could not find any changes in the category setting to remove the RC2 as parent. Please suggest how would i make the sub category to root category.

Comment: by root categories you mean categories under Default Category ?

Comment: i have Default Category, RC1, RC2, RC3, RC4 and RC5 categories RC1 has become subcategory to RC2 i want to make it RC1 as root category as usual.

Comment: what i am asking is : are RC1, RC2, RC3, RC4, RC5 under Default Category ? or are these on the same level ?

Comment: also are you using these categories for multiple stores ?

Comment: no all the categories are root categories not under default category.

Comment: try using solution below in answer.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your question correctly, if you have moved a category to another and trying to make it again a root level (i.e default category level) category.

You need to open database and open table `catalog_category_entity` then check the category Id of the moved category from admin panel adjacent to category name while editing it, this is `entity_id` in this table.

Now change parent_id to '1' and path to 1/categoryid for this category and level to 1 and save.

This will solve your problem.

Hope this is fine.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply as there are few products so i deleted and created new one

Comment: I just used this same method to achieve the same result in Magento 2.